# Is it safe to pass auth token via iOS deep link?

Tags: ios, security, authentication

I'm designing a webapp/mobileapp security flow where there are no passwords, only an auth token sent to the phone via sms. Flaws in this?

### The plan:

- Phone receives sms link with embedded *invite token*  `http://domain.com/invite/ABCD`
- User clicks, goes to web app which asks user to install mobile app (via deep link, which passes same token `myapp://invite/ABCD`
- When app is loaded, invite token `ABCD` is sent to server and exchanged for an `auth token` and a `session token`.
- `Auth token` is stored permanently in local storage in app.
- `Session token` is used for successive api calls and valid for 24hrs then `Auth token` will be used again to exchange for new `session token`

---

```
                                                                +---+
                                                                |   |
+---------+ <---------------------------------------------------+   |
| Invite  |                                                     | S |
| Link    |                               send invite           | E |
| rec'd   |   +---------+   +--------+    token                 | R |
| via     |   |WebApp:  |   |        +----------------------->  | V |
| SMS     |   |deep     |   | ios App|                          | E |
|         +-> |linked   +-> |        |   receiv auth &          | R |
| (token) |   |to mobile|   |        |   session token          |   |
+---------+   |app      |   |        | <----------------------+ |   |
              |(install)|   |        |                          |   |
              |         |   |        |  use session token       |   |
              |         |   |        |  for all api calls       |   |
              +---------+   +--------+ +--------------------->  +---+
```

### Questions:

- Is it safe to pass the token via deep link?
- See any other flaws with this scenario?
- Is auth/session combo even needed? Rationale was that session expires 24h since its exposed more over the network, but since its over ssl, maybe i only need an auth token that is stored forever and also used for api auth?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it should work, but be careful of your user experience. You don't want people sharing the link and having unauthorized logins, instead of treating it like a private password. Making your invite links usable only once would make them similar to the "Magic Link" pattern that Slack uses, however I would avoid calling it "invite", since these tend to be things you would give to other people.